Python script to sort data
I've converted .txt file into .xlsx however the data output is not satisfying I have about 368 entries to edit. is there a way to separate this ?
here is the format I would like
what I want to achieve 
what I currently have
what I currently have

import pandas as pd

# Read data from the .txt file (replace with your actual file path)
input_path = r"C:\Log Files\PalletTrackCore-20240624101430.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(input_path, sep="\t", header=None)

# Transpose the DataFrame to organize data in columns with headers as rows
df_transposed = df.T

# Add column names (customize these based on your data)
column_names = ["Timestamp", "Gate", "RFID Scan 1", "RFID Scan 2", "Success", "GateResultStatus"]
df_transposed.columns = column_names

# Save the transposed DataFrame to an Excel file
output_path = r"C:\Log Files\PalletTrackCore-20240624101430.xlsx"
df_transposed.to_excel(output_path, index=False)

# Print a success message
print(f"Data transposed and saved to {output_path}")


Are you saying that this code does what you need? If not, why have you posted it as an answer?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Some context please, is this part of the question or an answer?  Could be answer though the column_names do not match the 'what I want to achieve' column names.

This code does not do what i need i just posted to to show what i am using.

Scan initiated at 21/06/2024 09:13:20
ProcessGate() Gate:5;  RFID Scan 1:00353971424406254267
ProcessGate() Gate:5;  RFID Scan 2:00353971424406254250
SetSsccResultStatus() Scan ID:1; Gate:5; Success:True; SSCC:353971424406254267; Result:
SetSsccResultStatus() Scan ID:2; Gate:5; Success:True; SSCC:353971424406254250; Result:
SetGateResultStatus() Gate:5; Success:True; Result:SSCC data successfully processed
and i need to sort them by colums and rows , column would be scanned at , gate number , rfid scan 1 , rfid scan 2 , get rfid scan result for 1 & 2 & show gateresult status message
